# Show "not supported" text if browser does not support <embed /> tag?

Tags: html, video, cross-browser, embed

I've got a `.swf` file embedded on my page that looks something like this:

```
<embed src="/db/xxxx/stream.swf" />
```

It works fine, but I'm wondering how I can display some text like:

> Your browser does not support the embed tag.

if, well, the browser doesn't support the embed tag.

With `<video>` tags, I just do this:

```
<video src="/db/xxxx/stream.m4v">
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

That works fine, but the `<embed />` tag is self-closing, so it doesn't work the same way.

**How can I display "not supported" text in the** `<embed />` **tag if the browser does not support the tag?**

Comment: `<embed src="/db/xxxx/stream.swf" alt="Sorry, your browser doesn't support the embed tag!"/>`

Comment: That actually does not work. It breaks the embedded file. @TylerH

Comment: Hmm, I didn't realize it was so poorly implemented. Why are you using <embed> instead of <video> anyway?

Comment: I thought that `<embed />` supported `.swf` files while `<video>` does not. @TylerH

Comment: I thought embed was supported in all major browsers... but flash isnt. Are you sure the problem isnt flash instead of embed?

Comment: I have no idea what you're getting at. As I said in the question, the flash works fine. It's the "not supported" text that I'm trying to get working. @GaryHayes

Comment: @kehrk Try `<video> <object type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="flashlocationhere" width=X height=Y> <param>s goes here </object></video>`

Comment: Actually, the `alt` attribute doesn't break the element anymore. Strange. @TylerH

Comment: @kehrk Odd. test extensively on other environments/browsers!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `<embed>` tag is supported in all the major browsers. So the embed tag itself is supported, it's the content that the embed tag attempts to display that isn't supported.

You mention a swf file in your question. A lot of times a Javascript solution like [SWFObject](https://code.google.com/p/swfobject/) is used to figure out if Flash is available, and replace an element on the page with the Flash movie if flash is available. And if Flash isn't available, your alternate, or "Not supported" content would display instead.

Comment: For HTML5, yes. For XHTML or HTML4, no.

Comment: @TylerH Correct, `<embed>` is not apart of the HTML4 or XHTML spec, and would fail to validate. But it is supported by the browsers.